# How to add localised holidays to iCal

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

How can I add a localised holiday calendar to iCal? I would like to add all public holidays to iCal/iCloud, how to best do this?

(Personally I'm after the Norwegian and Australian Holidays, but I'm after a general answer.)

Answer (score 5):

Apple has many calendars you can add: http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/

Comment: Looks like they haven't been updated in 3 years.

Comment: The list may not be updated, but the calendars are fine. I have two country holiday calendars and they're always correct.

Comment: May be because they follow the Gregorian calendar. Holidays for my country aren't updated.

Comment: The list URL no longer links to anything useful

Answer (score 1):

Just found official Apple calendar for French holidays at: `webcal://files.apple.com/calendars/French32Holidays.ics`

I guess from that URL we can derive a generic scheme for other localized iCal sources.

Answer (score 0):

update of the calendar files are not easy to find, however as indicated [here](http://www.outlook-tips.net/outlook-calendar/missing-holidays/), microsoft released a new holiday patch in july2012 for holidays up to 2022 ([here](http://www.outlook-tips.net/files/OUTLOOK.HOL)).

Given a minimal editing it could be converted to ical and then imported.

For instance for Norway one would need to write following for the first 2 instances of Ascension (for more dtails on the syntax:[RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545))

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:pyICSParser
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:Ascension2012
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120517
SUMMARY:Ascension
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:Ascension2013
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120509
SUMMARY:Ascension
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Can you describe the required editing for other users?

Comment: just done so with example ical file

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 examples of iCloud calendars from which you can extrapolate the one that fits your needs:

- French holidays:

  https://p01-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/FR_fr.ics
- Swiss holidays:

  https://p01-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/CH_fr.ics
- Spanish holidays:

  https://p01-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/ES_es.ics